# Android отправка post запроса с параметра используя okhttp

Tags: java, android, post, request

Нужна помощь в решении одной проблемы! Недавно начал изучать программирование под Android, и возникла задачка, которую не могу решить. Необходимо отправлять на ресурс post запросы с параметрами. Как frontend использую python flask. 
Код python:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello_world():
    print request.json
    return 'True'


if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(host='192.168.1.100', port='5000')
```

Тут всё нормально вроде, банально просто и без заморочек, а главное работает.
А вот с Android печаль, использую okhttp модуль. Вот код:

```
package com.example.sanek.lessons1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json charset=utf-8");
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onBtnPress(View view) {
    String json =  "{'test':'1'}";
    post("http://192.168.1.100:5000/", json, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseStr = response.body().string();
            } else {
            }
        }
    });
}

Call post(String url, String json, Callback callback) {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        Log.d("My App", obj.toString());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.e("My App", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + json + "\"");
    }
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
    Call call = client.newCall(request);
    call.enqueue(callback);
    return call;
}
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку в Android приложении должен отправится post запрос c параметром "{'test':'1'}". Запрос отправляется, вот ответ python flask

```
None
192.168.1.107 - - [23/Jun/2016 19:59:57] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Запрос приходит, только почему-то параметры не приходят, точнее, там None. Что я делаю не так? Может, есть какие-то другие решения?

Comment: Попробуй `print request.json`, дабы понять что все же приходит. Если там будет твой json, то проблема где-то в парсинге на сервере.

Comment: Возможно проблема в отсутствии **;** в `MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8")`